# Как в настройках приложения удалить ил изменить запись по индексу

Tags: c#

В настройках программы, в Properties.Settings.Default, есть запись типа StringCollection

Подскажите, как в этой настройке можно удалить или изменить запись по индексу?

Comment: А как вы пробовали? Что не получилось-то?

Comment: Пробовал так Properties.Settings.Default.cfgSipAccountIndex[i].Remove()

Comment: Он при этом просит "начальный индекс" и "длинну"

Comment: Если сделать так Properties.Settings.Default.cfgSipAccountIndex.Remove(), то он требует "значение", а мне надо, чтобы удалял по индексу..

Answer (score 1):

Ознакомьтесь на MSDN с документацией по [классу `StringCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) (кстати, почему используется этот устаревший класс?) и вы найдете там [метод `RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx), который "Удаляет строку по указанному индексу StringCollection.":

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyStringCollection.RemoveAt(5);
```

Для изменения значения по индексу используйте [индексатор](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyStringCollection[5] = "new string";
```